# Sort a ko.observableArray([]) having 10 string value

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, ko.observablearray

I am having a `ko.observableArray([])` having *10* string names in both case, want it to be in sorted order.

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: What you tried ? It's not good quality question , See this [fag](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: vm.sortUsers().sort(function (a, b) {
        return a.Name().toLowerCase() > b.Name().toLowerCase() ? 1 : -1;
    }); I tried this but it is not sorting in the correct order.

Comment: @RameshRajendran That is no reason to call him a slur...  Mona check the docs it is very clear there how to do it.

Comment: @monamehta, if your still stuck, can you share the code? Esp. what kind of data you have in `vm.sortUsers()`?

Comment: @SDG-ShubhDasgupta- this.insertUser = function (user) {
$.each(user, function (i, v) {
vm.allUsers.push(v);
});
vm.allUsers().sort(function (a, b) { return a.Name > b.Name; });
}

Answer (score 1):

We need to `manually define the comparison function` that sorts an array alphabetically, which in turn allows us to specify where this string data is located. Take a look at the following: [**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/InizENI/6/edit?js,output)

Use `javascript` to achieve it,

```
var temp = users().sort(function (a, b) {
    var nameA = a.First.toLowerCase(),//Here 'First' is the attribute present in users()
        nameB = b.First.toLowerCase()
        if (nameA < nameB) //sort string ascending
            return -1
        if (nameA > nameB)
            return 1
        return 0 //default return value (no sorting)
})
```

In your case it should be :-

```
    vm.allUsers().sort(function (a, b) {
        var nameA = a.Name.toLowerCase(),
            nameB = b.Name.toLowerCase()
            if (nameA < nameB) //sort string ascending
                return -1
            if (nameA > nameB)
                return 1
            return 0 //default return value (no sorting)
    });
```

This will sort the employees array by the name property ascending, so employee[0] is "Ashutosh", employee[1](http://jsbin.com/InizENI/6/edit?js,output) is "Manisha" and so on.

Here we are comparing two strings `a.name` to `b.name` and returning either `-1, 1, or 0` accordingly to sort, exactly the formula used inexplicitly by the sort() method without any function passed in.

And as you might have just discovered, in JavaScript you can certainly compare two string (done so alphabetically). For more details you can look into [javascriptkit](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/arraysort2.shtml)